# Outgoing SSH connection to particular domain on MacOS times out

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm trying to SSH into a server from my laptop:

```
$ ssh -F /dev/null admin@domain.com -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 31000 -vv
```

I get the error:

> ssh: connect to host domain.com port 31000: Operation timed out

If I check Little Snitch, the SSH outgoing connected was never made.

If I try my staging server:

```
$ ssh -F /dev/null admin@staging.domain.com -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 31000 -vv
```

everything is OK and I can see the outgoing connection in Little Snitch.

So this leads me to believe it's either being blocked by either SSH, my local hosts file, or via some sort of local DNS issue

- I can `ping`, `dig` and `traceroute` the domain.com OK
- I can `nmap` it via `sudo nmap -Pn -p31000 domain.com`
- I've cleared `~/.ssh/known_hosts`
- There's nothing relevent in either `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
- I don't have anything in my local `ssh_config` that would block an outgoing connection
- I've checked `/etc/hosts` and there's no mention of `domain.com`

What else could be preventing my outgoing connection?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was related to CloudFlare on the target server. I didn't notice that the IP being returned via `dig` was actually the IP for the CloudFlare proxy server and not the original DO server. So this was a DNS issue.

I'm still not sure why the outgoing connection wasn't showing in Little Snitch, I imagine it has something to do with it only being visible once succesfully connected.